# How to combine $in and max in MongoDb?

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to get max timestamp of a set of tags from MongoDb history database. Say the tag ids are 1,2,3,4,5 I want to check all records for these tags and get the timestamp of latest. My collection looks like this along with data:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
protected Timestamp getMaxRealTimeHistoryTimestamp(List<Integer> tagIds)
{
    try
    {
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(m_connectionInfo.getHost(), m_connectionInfo.getPort());
        //Connecting to the database
        MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase(m_connectionInfo.getDatabaseName());

        BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<>();
        obj.add(new BasicDBObject("TAG_ID", new BasicDBObject("$in", tagIds)));


        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("EM_HISTORY");
        Document doc = collection.find(andQuery).sort(new Document("TIME_STAMP", -1)).first();

        if(doc != null)
        {
            return new Timestamp(((Date) doc.get("TIME_STAMP")).getTime());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (Logger.isErrorEnabled())
            Logger.error(e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

the doc variable has some strange row that is not even in the collection

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "the doc variable has some strange row that is not even in the collection". It won't have made up that result, it must be in the collection. Check for `_id: 19029`.

Comment: @Thilo Already did that last _id is 18390. No data was entered today as simulator is not on, still it has today's date.

Comment: You have larger _id than 18390 in the screen shot you posted.

Comment: @Thilo Sorry, i guess I didn't sort that properly, but time value still shows wrong value.
[
  {
    "_id": 19029,
    "QUALITY": 192,
    "TAG_ID": 578,
    "TIME_STAMP": {"$date": "2021-03-13T18:37:16.358Z"},
    "VALUE": 0
  }
]Timestamp is in UTC. Guess there is some problem with time zone. still difference is too large as IST is +5.30

Comment: You don't seem to be adding that filter (`obj`) to your `andQuery` at all.

Comment: @Thilo yes, it works now. Thanks a lot it was a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();
List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<>();
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("TAG_ID", new BasicDBObject("$in", tagIds)));
```

You are never adding the query filters from `obj` back into your `andQuery`, so the code ends up querying the collection without any filter.